# Laravel send SSH command

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

I'm working on a Laravel app and would need to send a SSH command to a remote server from my webapp. I know envoy can be used to this but this is not a good solution for me as envoy allows only to send a predefined command to a predefined list of servers.

In my case, I need to send a SSH command to a remote server when clicking on a button in my webapp to the IP address of a remote server that can be found on a label in the webapp.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is always a good idea to stick to the language standard library if it provides the functionality you need. Please have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

Comment: Plus, this has more details just in case http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/24/make-ssh-connections-with-php/